# get data from json api but not displaying it in an html table

Tags: javascript, html, css, datatables

I am interested in how to retrieve data from a website and display it in html. then I found an example from a website and tried changing some code in it. but then the existing data is not displayed by the browser. this is an example:

```js
</scrypt>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "ajax": "https://www.zpool.ca/api/miners",

            column: [{
                "algo"
            }, {
                "version"
            }, {
                "count"
    }]
  });
});</scrypt>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js'/>
<script src='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'/>
    <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Algo</th>
                <th>Version</th>
                <th>Count</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Algo</th>
                <th>Version</th>
                <th>Count</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

can some one fix this ??

Comment: Are you getting a CORS error?

Comment: scrypt is misspelled?

Comment: @ecg8,@noor I don't know where the error is, because in vs code the error was not raised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the docs before posting a question, there is an exact example there 
https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/custom_data_flat.html

fixed code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": {
            "url": "https://www.zpool.ca/api/miners",
            "dataSrc": ""
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "algo" },
            { "data": "version" },
            { "data": "count" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Comment: yes, the code comes from there. but after being changed I don't know where the error is.

Comment: this version worked for me, you're probably experiencing CORS issues now, try using an extension on your browser to disable the policy

Comment: I use the Chrome browser, where is the policy setting located?

Comment: for chrome and edge all stops in the load process. and for ie it doesn't mean change at all

Comment: hmm.. I turned out to use third party help for the chrome add-on. and the problem is finished here. next I will continue with some related things. Thank you for the advice.